# Using maven and embedded jetty: ClassCastException

Tags: maven-2, jetty, cargo, maven-cargo

I have a web-application written in java.

I would like to run integration tests on a embedded jetty server.

For that purpose I have a maven project (just for running integration tests).

For deploying I use cargo-maven2-plugin. But while jetty startup I receive following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration cannot be cast to org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.Configuration
```

Full log:

```
[beddedLocalContainer] Jetty 6.x Embedded starting...
2010-03-29 16:20:46.615::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2010-03-29 16:20:46.715::INFO:  jetty-6.1.1rc1
2010-03-29 16:20:46.980::INFO:  Extract jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Alpha/Local%20Settings/Temp/cargo/conf/cargocpc.war!/ to C:\DOCUME~1\Alpha\LOCALS~1\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_cargocpc.war__cargocpc__xflgf3\webapp
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2010-03-29 16:20:47.897::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8080
[beddedLocalContainer] Jetty 6.x Embedded started on port [8080]
[cargo:deployer]
[mbeddedLocalDeployer] Deploying [c:\maven-repo\myapp\2.1-SNAPSHOT\myapp-2.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
2010-03-29 16:20:51.711::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@132e910{/myapp,c:\maven-repo\myapp\2.1-SNAPSHOT\myapp-2.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration cannot be cast to org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.Configuration
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.loadConfigurations(WebAppContext.java:801)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:403)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.Jetty6xEmbeddedLocalContainer.addHandler(Jetty6xEmbeddedLocalContainer.java:294)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.Jetty6xEmbeddedLocalDeployer.deployWebApp(Jetty6xEmbeddedLocalDeployer.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jetty.internal.AbstractJettyEmbeddedLocalDeployer.deploy(AbstractJettyEmbeddedLocalDeployer.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.DeployerDeployMojo.performDeployerActionOnSingleDeployable(DeployerDeployMojo.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.performDeployerActionOnAllDeployables(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:104)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractDeployerMojo.doExecute(AbstractDeployerMojo.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Maven cargo settings:

```
<profile>
<id>container-cargo-jetty</id>
<properties>
    <skip.test.phase>true</skip.test.phase>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                        <cargo.logging>medium</cargo.logging>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployer>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>myapp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>/myapp</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </deployer>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-embedded</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.22</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the version of the embedded Jetty used by Cargo is not supported (there is an old open issue about that, see [CARGO-571](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-571)). And indeed, if we look at the log, we see that it uses jetty-6.1.1rc1:

```
2010-03-29 16:20:46.715::INFO:  jetty-6.1.1rc1
```

So, first, remove the jetty dependency inside the plugin configuration which is actually the cause of the `ClassCastException`.

But once the dependency removed, I faced another obscure commons-logging issue:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.
```

And the cause seems to be this part:

```
            <execution>
                <id>start-container</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                    <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
```

To be honest, I don't know why you call the `deploy-deploy` goal here. Without it, Cargo does deploy the declared `deployable`. So there is IMO no need to specify this goal. And if you remove it, there is no exception (and that the second "fix").

To summarize, the following configuration works:

```
<profile>
  <id>container-cargo-jetty</id>
  <properties>
    <skip.test.phase>true</skip.test.phase>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <wait>false</wait>
          <container>
            <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
            <type>embedded</type>
          </container>
          <configuration>
           <properties>
             <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
             <cargo.logging>medium</cargo.logging>
            </properties>
          </configuration>
          <deployer>
            <deployables>
              <deployable>
                <groupId>myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <properties>
                  <context>/myapp</context>
                </properties>
              </deployable>
            </deployables>
          </deployer>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-container</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-container</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Without goal 'deploy-deploy' the application will be NOT deployed. I had class loader problems with Apache commons logging. Finally I switched to jetty-maven-plugin.

Comment: @amra Weird, it DOES work for me without `deploy-deploy` (I tested this before posting).

Answer (score 2):

You may be dealing with "classloader hell" in JETTY, where it uses a parent classloader for the JETTY instance which is separate from the one used for your webapplication and so even though they should be identical classes they aren't.

There are some options in the JETTY configuration to force use of the same classloader, that may help in your integration tests.

[Classloading - JETTY](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading)

> Jetty provides configuration options
>   to control all three of these options.
>   The method
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(boolean)
>   allows the normal java 2 behaviour to
>   be used and all classes will be loaded
>   from the system classpath if possible.
>   This is very useful if the libraries
>   that a web application uses are having
>   problems loading classes that are both
>   in a web application and on the system
>   classpath.

I'm not sure how you access JETTY configuration in Cargo, but in the normal JETTY maven plugin you would do something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
    <configuration>
        <jettyConfig>${jetty.configs}</jettyConfig>
        <reload>manual</reload>
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        <webAppConfig>
            <parentLoaderPriority>true</parentLoaderPriority>

        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```